# $scope array not getting updated

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Inside a controller I have this code:

```
$rootScope.$on('chat_contact', function(event, data) {          
            var message = data.message;
            if(data.key === 'IM_MSG') {
                console.log("chat_contact.........");
                var contact = $scope.contacts[message.sndrId];
                if(contact) {
                    contact.lastMsg = message.text;
                    contact.sndrName = message.sndrName;
                } else {
                    $scope.contacts[7] = {
                        'lastMsg': message.text,
                        'sndrName': message.sndrName 
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is my html code:

```
    <li class="item item-avatar item-icon-left1 item-icon-right" ng-repeat="(id, contact) in contacts" ui-sref="app.chat-single" on-hold="moreOptions('{{id}}')">
      <img src="venkman.jpg">
      <h2>{{contact.sndrName}}</h2>
      <p><span class='margin-l-10'>{{contact.lastMsg}}</span></p>
```

Problem is

```
$scope.contacts[7] = {
  'lastMsg': message.text,
  'sndrName': message.sndrName 
}
```

is adding a new enter to `contacts` but its not getting render in html

Comment: Where are you adding?\

Comment: inside a controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try adding $apply() ?

I was facing the same problem and it resolved mine.

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.contacts[7] = {
    'lastMsg': message.text,
    'sndrName': message.sndrName 
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if it's correct but you can give it a try.

Comment: But why its happening like that simply adding to $scope should update the data

Comment: @manish usually if you change data inside an event you need to $apply()

Comment: adding to what @gyc stated, $apply evaluates an expression and triggers a digest cycle, making Angular execute all registered watch listeners and update any view bindings.

Comment: @gyc we can add any data to $scope under a click to other event correct & it generally reflect the changes

Comment: @manish yes, the ngClick directive includes $apply() in source code

Comment: Does that mean $on do not wrap  $apply()

Answer (score 1):

use $scope.$apply(); after the loop execution

```
$rootScope.$on('chat_contact', function(event, data) {          
        var message = data.message;
        if(data.key === 'IM_MSG') {
            console.log("chat_contact.........");
            var contact = $scope.contacts[message.sndrId];
            if(contact) {
                contact.lastMsg = message.text;
                contact.sndrName = message.sndrName;
            } else {
                $scope.contacts[7] = {
                    'lastMsg': message.text,
                    'sndrName': message.sndrName 
                }
            $scope.$apply();
            }
        }
    });
```